# Couldn't write the script in python for this program, Can someone please recommend anything to make it work

Tags: python

wants to know the temperature of City in immutable list for a specific purpose. They have certain criterions to solve this problem. The criterions are given below:
SL NO   Requirement Specification
1   Provide an option where they can take temperature in either Fahrenheit or Celsius scale
2   Take input of how many temperature values you want to take
3                  Put them in a list or take the input of entire list
3   Convert the temperature from the Celsius to Fahrenheit or vice versa and print them

The Conversion Formula for Fahrenheit to Celsius is given below:
T(°C) = (T(°F)  - 32) × 5/9  Here T(°C)  refers to the temperature in Celsius and T(°F)  is defined for Fahrenheit temperature.
The Conversion formula for Celsius to Fahrenheit is given below:
T(°F) = T(°C) × 9/5 + 32 Here T(°C)  refers to the temperature in Celsius and T(°F)  is defined for Fahrenheit temperature.
Please write a python script for this. Please include at least one user defined function. You can convert the list into tuple using the tuple() function.

my script so far is as below;

```
n=int(input("Please enter the temperature observation"))
emptyList1=float[]
emptyList2 = float[]
C = float
F = float
for i in range (0,n):
        t=(i+1 ," th Value")
        emptyList1.append(t)
def C ():
    C = (t-32)*(5/9)
def F ():
    F = (t*(9/5)) + 32
print( "Enter C if the given temperature is in Fahrenheit and want to convert in Celcius, F if the temperature is in Celcius and want to convert in Farhenheit")
choice = input('Please enter your selected option: ')
if (choice==C):
    C()
elif (choice==F):
    F()
for t in range (emptyList1):
    t1 = C(t)
    emptyList2.append(t)
```

Comment: `C = float` is wrong - you can't assign a type to a variable like that.

Comment: My only recommendation is to actually do some python tutorial. Your code has a clear lack of understanding of basic python principles (like return in functions and creating a list)

Comment: Also, `if (choice == C)` is wrong - I assume that you meant `if (choice == 'C')`. You want to compare it to a string, not to the variable `C`. Also, I suggest that you not make your variables and methods have the same name like that.

Answer (score 0):

This has numerous syntactic problems.

First, don't name your variables and methods the same thing.

Secondly, it doesn't make sense to assign a type to a variable (e.g. `C = float`).

Third, you shouldn't have the `C` or `F` variables in the first place - just return a value from your methods.

Finally, `if (choice == C)` should be `if (choice == 'C')` because you want to compare your input to the *string* `'C'`, not the variable named `C`.

Comment: OMG, yes you are right.... I was thinking I am doing something wrong but couldn't figure out.

Comment: I am basically very new to python and languages its just been few weeks, so yes there are many mistakes in my script and I am trying to learn, someone said I should go to Youtube tutorial, however youtube will not tell me where I am wrong, it is a reason why I am here, I wasn't looking for solution, just wanted some advice to make my script right which I got.

Thank you for your help I really appreciate it